# Doctrine selecting from joins based on multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am trying to make a selection based on multiple ids in joins, each of the ids should match another condition of another join.

I need to get "Types" that have all the "Dichotomies" in "Position" 1 or 2. At the moment it gives me results that match one of the Dichotomies passed to the function, but not all of them.

```
$QB->select("Types","Types,ElementsPositions, Elements, Positions, Dichotomies, Quadras,TypesDescriptions,Relations")
                ->from($this->get_repository()[0], 'Types');
                $QB->leftJoin("Types.ElementsPositions","ElementsPositions", \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'ElementsPositions.Positions = 1 OR ElementsPositions.Positions = 2');
                $QB->leftJoin("ElementsPositions.Elements","Elements");
                $QB->leftJoin("ElementsPositions.Positions","Positions");
                $QB->leftJoin("Elements.Dichotomies","Dichotomies");
                $QB->leftJoin("Types.Quadras","Quadras");
                $QB->leftJoin("Types.TypesDescriptions","TypesDescriptions");
                $QB->leftJoin("Types.Relations","Relations");

    if(!empty($where['dichotomies'])){
        foreach($where['dichotomies'] as $dichotomy){
                $QB->andWhere('Dichotomies.id'.'=:dichotomy');
                $QB->setParameter('dichotomy', $dichotomy['id']);                
        }            
    }
```

UPD. 
Tables mapping - in JSON:

```
{
"table-name": "types",    
"joins":[
    {
        "table-name":"elements_positions",
        "type":"one-to-many"
    },
    {
        "table-name":"quadras",
        "type":"many-to-one"
    },
    {
        "table-name":"types_descriptions",
        "type":"one-to-one"
    },
    {
        "table-name":"relations",
        "type":"many-to-one"
    }
]}
```

Elements Positions

```
{
    "table-name": "elements_positions",
    "joins":[
        {
            "table-name":"elements",
            "type":"many-to-one"
        },
        {
            "table-name":"positions",
            "type":"many-to-one"
        },
        {
            "table-name":"types",
            "type":"many-to-one"
        }
    ]
}
```

Elements

```
 {
        "table-name": "elements",    
        "joins":[
            {
                "table-name":"elements_positions",
                "type":"one-to-many"
            },
            {
                "table-name":"quadras",
                "type":"many-to-many"
            },
            {
                "table-name":"dichotomies",
                "type":"many-to-many"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Positions

```
    "table-name": "positions",    
    "joins":[
        {
            "table-name":"elements_positions",
            "type":"one-to-many"
        }
    ]
}
```

Dichotomies:

```
{
    "table-name": "dichotomies",
    "joins":[
        {
            "table-name":"elements",
            "type":"many-to-many-inversed"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query has a two different problems.

First, multiple parameter values are bound with single parameter. Every next element of `$where['dichotomies']` replaces previous value of parameter `:dichotomy` in the query. The method setParameters() don't really binds values to the prepared statement: it just stores them in QueryBuilder object. So, after the end of foreach-loop all conditions will be use the same value (the last of `$where['dichotomies']`). To avoid that you need to use different parameter names or numeric indexes.

Second, you add conditions that are contradictory: `$QB->andWhere()` will produce something like that:

```
Dichotomies.id = :dichotomy 
AND Dichotomies.id = :dichotomy 
AND Dichotomies.id = :dichotomy 
...
```

One entity ID obviously cannot be equal to different values simultaneously. So, you need to replace `AND` by the `OR` operator.

But better way is to use `IN` clause:

> Calling [`setParameter()`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query) automatically infers which type you are setting as value. This works for integers, **arrays of strings/integers**, DateTime instances and for managed entities.

Just replace the foreach-loop by the following lines:

```
$QB->andWhere('Dichotomies.id IN (:dichotomies)');
$QB->setParameters('dichotomies', array_column($where['dichotomies'], 'id'));
```

The [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) function returns a list of IDs of all dichotomies. Doctrine generates `IN` expression and uses that list to generate query placeholders and bind the values.

Comment: Oh, yes, setParameter() was overwriting it each time indeed!
But the Dichotomies table is the inversed side of many-to-many to Elements, and Elements are one-to-many to ElementsPositions which has three joins-Types, Elements and Positions. So a Type can have two Dichotomies (via Elements) in Position 1 and 2 and I need to filter out by 2 $dichotomies that are provided - both have to be in position 1 or 2. That's why "and" not "or". But that doesn't work-gives me no results with 2 dichotomies sent, and if I change to "or"-gives me results that match either of the two.

Comment: Sorry, but it's a bit hard to understand. May you edit your query and provide a native SQL query that you want to get?

Comment: I am afraid if I knew it in pure SQL, I would be able to translate.What I am trying to say, table "Types" can have multiple "Dichotomies" and "Dichotomies" of "Type" have "Positions". I need to check that both(2) "Dichotomies" of a "Type" are in "Positions" 1 or 2. Am I conceptually wrong here?

Comment: i don't sure that i correctly understand your domain model and i find it difficult to help without schema and mapping.

Comment: I have updated the original post with mapping in JSON format - hope this helps...